# Having trouble finding an angle given an equation including radians (statics equilibrium problem)

Tags: trigonometry, classical-mechanics, angle

I'm doing some Engineering Mechanics homework regarding equilibrium of rigid bodies and I've come across a problem involving radians that has stomped me.  I have the question and the steps to find the answer in the image attachments, but I don't understand how they figured out how to find the radians.  I would try and type out the steps they took but it wouldn't make sense without seeing the image in the question.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmqTW.png)

I have to find the angle that the rod makes from the horizontal so that the rod is in equilibrium.  There's a linear torsional spring that deforms, applying a couple moment $ M $ related to the spring's rotation $ \theta $ in radians: $ M=40\theta\ {N\cdot m} $.
 There's also the gravitational force acting in the center of the rod.  Whenever I used the equation to sum the moments to zero, I got stuck.

$$
\Sigma \, M_{A}\, = \, (245.25 \: N)(cos(\theta \cdot\frac{180}{\pi} ))(0.25 \:m)\, + \, 40\theta\,  N\!  \cdot\!  m = 0
$$

I can't figure out how I'm supposed to solve for $ \theta $ if it is both inside and outside the cosine.  Here is the solution I found, but it didn't help me.

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB2Ou.png)

If anyone could help explain how the final answer can be found I'd greatly appreciate it.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Equations which mix polynomial and trigonometric functions do not show analytical solutions; this is already the case for $x=\cos(x)$. Only numerical methods (such as Newton) will do the job.

Comment: About it being in radians: If you see. inside $\cos$, the angle is given as $\theta \times\frac{180}{\pi}$, where $\times\frac{180}{\pi}$ is to convert $\theta$ in radians to degree. Hence, solving for $\theta$ will give you an answer in radians, which is later converted to degree.